# Result set is not displaying in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I type the information in the `TextBox` there is no result in the `GridView` only the URL Parameter appear.

For example.

```
FNameTextBox.Text = "Mark"
```

The result is nothing just the URL says that

```
http://localhost:65319/Example.aspx?FirstName=Mark
```

In the `GridView` there is no result.

This is my current code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using con As New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=WJNJPHR8TCX8P\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Fabrics;Integrated Security=True;"),
      cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [Client] WHERE [ClientId] = ? OR [FirstName] = ? OR [MiddleName] = ? OR [LastName] = ?", con)
            con.Open()

            If IsNumeric(idTextBox.Text) Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientId", OdbcType.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(idTextBox.Text)
                Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?ClientId=" + idTextBox.Text)
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientId", OdbcType.Int).Value = -1
            End If

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = FNameTextBox.Text
            Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?FirstName=" + FNameTextBox.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = MNameTextBox.Text
            Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?MiddleName=" + MNameTextBox.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = LNameTextBox.Text
            Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?LastName=" + LNameTextBox.Text)

            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        End Using

        GridView1.DataSourceID = Nothing
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Question:

How can I display the Result set in `GridView`?

Answer (score 0):

Why using `Response.Redirect`? comment all of them and your code is working.

Comment: Because of 3 `Response.Redirect` statements... certainly `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())` to load grid data never executed then.

Comment: I change the syntax to Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?CLientId=" + idTextBox.Text + "&FirstName=" + FNameTextBox.Text + "&MiddleName=" + MNameTextBox.Text + "&LastName=" + LNameTextBox.Text) still no result in gridview

Comment: Why you need redirect at thr first place?

Comment: I used it to redirect me to another web form and get the Query string @Imad

Comment: If you can suggest other than redirect. Feel free to suggest. @Imad

Comment: But if you redirect how will you see result on grid view. Try to just remove redirect and you will be getting result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send first name, middle name, last name as a query string, you should firstly store all the values then redirect to another page, or send all the textbox values in single query string.

```
String fname =  fNameTextBox.Text
String mname =  mNameTextBox.Text
String lname =  lNameTextBox.Text

Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?FirstName="+fname+"&MName="+mname+"&LastName=" + lname)
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("Example.aspx?FirstName="+fNameTextBox.text+"&MName="+mNameTextBox.text+"&LastName=" + lNameTextBox.text)
```